# TypeError: handler is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, typeerror

I have a form with attributes that I am sending to a JS function. This function is used in another JS file. When I submit my form I get `TypeError: handler is undefined`

[image: console error screenshot]

Im still new to JS, but what puzzles me is that it is capturing the data correctly (as seen in the first line of the image) , but on submit its not passing appropriately. A prior version of the script was successful but I had to modify the method and not its not working anymore. So I really think its the script. or could it be some missing jquery/ajax/ reference? Thanks!

Here is the script:

```
<script>
var PLAN_CONFIG = {
  id: '',
  billing: 'annual',
  name: '',
  description: '',
  payment: '',
  panelLabel: 'Confirm',
};


$('[name=radiobtn]').click(function () {
  PLAN_CONFIG.billing = $(this).attr('value');
  console.log(PLAN_CONFIG);
});

$('#dropdown li').click(function () {
  $(".dd-button:first-child").text($(this).text());
  PLAN_CONFIG.id = $(this).attr('data-value');
  PLAN_CONFIG.name = $(this).data('name');
  PLAN_CONFIG.description = $(this).data('description');
  PLAN_CONFIG.payment = $(this).data('payment');
  console.log(PLAN_CONFIG);

});

</script>
```

JS file (submission.js):

```
// checkout handler
var handler;
if (PLAN_CONFIG['payment'] === true) {
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'key',
    image: '/images/gavel.png',
    token: function(token) {
      /* Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
      You can access the token ID with `token.id`
      Pass along various parameters you get from the token response
      and your form.*/                    
      var myData = {
        billing: PLAN_CONFIG['billing'],
        token: token.id,
        email: token.email,
      };

      /* Make an AJAX post request using JQuery,
      change the first parameter to your charge script*/
      $.post("/create_subscription.php?plan=" + PLAN_CONFIG['id'], myData, function (data) {
        // if you get some results back update results
        $("#FormSubmission").hide()
        window.location.replace("http://thankyou.com");
      }).fail(function () {
        // if things fail, tell us
        window.location.replace("http://oops.com");
      })
    }
  });
}


$("#SubmissionButton").on('click', function() {
  submitToIS();

  if ((PLAN_CONFIG['payment']) == true) {
    launchStripeForm();
  }
});

$('#FormSubmission').on('submit', function (e) {
  submitToIS();

  if ((PLAN_CONFIG['payment']) == true) {
    launchStripeForm();
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});



function submitToIS() {
  $.ajax ({
    url:"/create_contact.php?plan=" + PLAN_CONFIG['id'],
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      // billing: PLAN_CONFIG['billing'],
      firstname: $("#firstname").val(),
      lastname: $("#lastname").val(),
      phonenumber: $("#phonenumber").val(),
      email: $("#email").val(),
      company: $("#company").val(),

    },

    success: function(response){
      if ((PLAN_CONFIG['payment']) == false) {
        window.location.replace("http://thankyou.com");
      }
      console.log(response);
    },

    fail: function(){
      if ((PLAN_CONFIG['payment']) == false) {
        window.location.replace("http://oops.com");
      }
    },

  })
}

function launchStripeForm() {

  handler.open({
    name: PLAN_CONFIG['name'],
    description: PLAN_CONFIG['description'],
    allowRememberMe: false, 
    email: $("#email").val(),
    panelLabel: PLAN_CONFIG['panelLabel'],
  });
}

// Close Checkout on page navigation
// $(window).on('popstate', function () {
//   handler.close();
// });
```

note: I changed some urls and fxn names for privacy. Also, the forms on my other pages reference this same JS file but they submit successfully. I feel like the error is in the script and not the file.

Comment: It looks like your variable `handler` never gets assigned, which is why it's undefined. That assignment happens in this if block: `if (PLAN_CONFIG['payment'] === true) {`. So, I'd venture a guess that `PLAN_CONFIG['payment']` is never assigned to true. That happens in your `li` click handler, so I'm guessing your payment attribute isn't set to true on that `li` or it's a string of `true` that needs casting.

Comment: @wholevinski ive set it as true by default in my script (in var PLAN_CONFIG.... payment :  'true' ) but im still coming across the same error. also , it was defined as true in the console when i output the object. What do you mean by casting?

Comment: The casting comment was if you were storing it as a string `"true"` somewhere Vs. a bool `true` in your if statement. Since it still wasn't assigned with a default value, I'll take another look at it.

Comment: Even if you "force a `true` to `PLAN_CONFIG['payment']`... When the code gets parsed, the `handler` in `handler.open({` is undefined... So that function can't be parsed... I'm pretty sure that the error is fired on that specific line. -- I would place the condition `if (PLAN_CONFIG['payment'] === true) {` to wrap the opening instead of the "defining". ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette so how do i fix it? do i wrap it in a statement that only executes it when `handler` has been populated?

Comment: That's what I would try for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move your condition around the `.open()` instead of around the `handler` definition.

```
// checkout handler

// Define anyway!! Even if wrongly defined... If it doesn't run in the end, there is no problem.
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'key',
  image: '/images/gavel.png',
  token: function(token) {
    /* Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
    You can access the token ID with `token.id`
    Pass along various parameters you get from the token response
    and your form.*/                    
    var myData = {
      billing: PLAN_CONFIG['billing'],
      token: token.id,
      email: token.email,
    };

    /* Make an AJAX post request using JQuery,
    change the first parameter to your charge script*/
    $.post("/create_subscription.php?plan=" + PLAN_CONFIG['id'], myData, function (data) {
      // if you get some results back update results
      $("#FormSubmission").hide()
      window.location.replace("http://thankyou.com");
    }).fail(function () {
      // if things fail, tell us
      window.location.replace("http://oops.com");
    })
  }
});


// .....

function launchStripeForm() {
  if (PLAN_CONFIG['payment'] === true) {    // The RUN condition should be here.
    handler.open({
      name: PLAN_CONFIG['name'],
      description: PLAN_CONFIG['description'],
      allowRememberMe: false, 
      email: $("#email").val(),
      panelLabel: PLAN_CONFIG['panelLabel'],
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a timing issue. Submission.js will be parsed long before any DOM events can be fired. This means, when your browser reads

```
var handler;
    if (PLAN_CONFIG['payment'] === true) {
        var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
...
```

While `handler` is declared, it will remain undefined because at that point in time, based on how you assign initial values to your plan configuration object, `PLAN_CONFIG['payment']` is an empty string, which evaluates to `false`.

You need to add some sort of init function to call before launching your stripe form so that handler has some value. There are multiple ways you could go about this.

FOR INSTANCE

```
var handler; // initialize the variable
function initStripeHandler() {
    handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: 'key',
        image: '/images/gavel.png',
        token: function(token) {...}
    });
}
```

And then, somewhere down in your code, before calling other functions dependent on handler, call:

```
initStripeHandler();
```

Comment: but in the picture i attached the values of the PLAN_CONFIG object are already passed as how they should. or is it that theyre passed when its already too late ?

Comment: When are those values being passed? Are those initial values or values that are generated later?

Comment: theyre being passed later except for billing and panellable , theyre already set as seen in the script above

Comment: but also, it was working before with the same variable definition. i just added three more assignments in the dropdown li .click function

Comment: I added an example to my answer. 

Things to check: what order are your JS files being loaded? Make sure `submission.js` is being loaded after your inline script. Also, just to be anal about possible issues I can't see, Stripe places the following warning on their site: ***Note: Checkout must be loaded directly from `https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js.` Using a local copy of Checkout is unsupported, and may result in user-visible errors.